# XPath predicate to compare selected node with context node?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, xpath-1.0

Suppose I have the following simplified nested HTML list:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

and now I’d like to visit every text node while iterating of the list items:

```py
for li in xml.xpath(".//li"):
    for t in li.xpath(".//text()"):
        print(t)
```

However, this prints `Item 2 1` twice because that text node is the descendant of two `li` nodes. So I want to select only those text nodes whose ancestor `li` is the current/context list item, so to avoid multi-selecting text nodes in nested list items. Something like

```py
li.xpath(".//text[ancestor::li[1] == .]")
```

but that’s an invalid expression.

How do I do that? (This is using [lxml](https://lxml.de/) which builds on [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) which implements XPath 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
for t in xml.xpath('//li[text()]'):
    print(t.text.strip()
```

Output:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 2 1
Item 3
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it can be noted that the following XPath 1.0 expression:

```
.//text()
```

is a shortcut (some "syntactic sugar") for `descendant-or-self::text()` − one of [the thirteen XPath 1.0 axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes).

So if you want to only get the text nodes that are "at the same level of the current node" (actually its direct children), you should just use the axis `child::text()`. This is the default axis BTW, so you can just write `text()`.

Relying on the example from your question:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from lxml import etree
with open('./a.xml') as data:
    xml = etree.parse(data)
    for li in xml.xpath(".//li"):
        print(li.xpath("text()"))
```

will output

```
['Item 1']
['Item 2\n    ', '\n  ']
['Item 2 1']
['Item 3']
```

Comment: The `text()` would not work for `<li>Some <em>text</em><ol>…</ol></li>` as it would not select the text nodes of `li`’s descendants.

Comment: But that's what you wanted, didn't you?

Comment: Given the outer loop will go into these nested `li` nodes…